# Review Queue filter drop-down cut off

Tags: bug, design

I have verified this only on English Language & Usage, [where I also posted on Meta,](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10882/review-queue-filter-drop-down-cut-off-screen) and it was recommended that I bring this here.

When you set a filter on the review queue, and then you complete all reviews that satisfy that filter, the filter drop-down gets cut off because it doesn't fit in the surrounding div.

[image]

A scrollbar appears, but it is on the far right of the screen as seen above, so figuring out how to clear your filter is not completely intuitive.  When you do scroll down, the other parts of the surrounding div get scrolled off-screen.

[image]

It seems that the drop-down should appear in full like it does when there is a question behind it.

Comment: AFAYK, is this a recent defect? When did you realise it?

Comment: There is really no need to cross post bugs: https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10882/review-queue-filter-drop-down-cut-off-screen

Comment: @Oded Sorry about that, I'll remember this moving forward.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Actually I just noticed this right before I posted the question, but it's definitely possible that the bug was there long before that and I simply hadn't noticed.

Comment: Not your fault  - you were given incorrect advice.